# Strange behavior in chrome (using a gameloop) with canvas

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following code:

```
    var gameStateRender = function (game) {

    var t = new Date();
    /* time passed since last frame */
    game.timePassed = t.getTime() - game.timeFrameStart;
    /* time when frame starts */
    game.timeFrameStart = t.getTime();
    /* time passed total */
    game.timeTotal += game.timePassed;
    game.update();
    game.draw();
    };

    /* set the default game-state */
    var gameState = gameStateRender;
```

I use `requestAnimFrame` and a fallback (`setTimeout`) with 60 fps.

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {

    return  window.requestAnimationFrame    || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame  || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame     || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame       || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame      || 
    function(callback) {

    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / game.fps);
    };
    })();

    (function gameloop () {

    requestAnimFrame(gameloop);
    gameState(game);

    })();
```

The game runs smooth in FF, IE9 and has a constant frame-rate of ~60 fps.

In chrome the game also has ~60 fps, but stutters. Some facts:

- While I move the mouse in chrome, the whole animation is smooth and when I stop moving the mouse the animation starts to stutter. The game always has ~60 fps (while I move the mouse and while not).
- While I use `console.log(...)`, the game runs smoothly, without printing stuff to the console, the game is stuttering again. (???)

  ```
  var gameStateRender = function (game) {

  var t = new Date();
  /* time passed since last frame */
  game.timePassed = t.getTime() - game.timeFrameStart;
  /* time when frame starts */
  game.timeFrameStart = t.getTime();
  /* time passed total */
  game.timeTotal += game.timePassed;

  console.log(game.timeTotal);

  game.update();
  game.draw();
  };
  ```

While I run the above code, the animation is smooth.
The game has in fact, always a frame-rate of ~60 (16ms per frame), which I've verified.

Has anyone had this (strange) behavior before? Sounds pretty strange to me.

Comment: i forgot: Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m

Comment: We probably need to see the update and draw methods to be able to actually assist you.

Comment: i don't thinck it has anything to do with my update or draw method. when i move the mouse or log something to the console, the update and draw-method is still the same and the animation starts to be smooth. i now tested it on someone elses computer. doesn't stutter there, so it is probably a hardware related issue or something else.